# How to port Eclipse projects from one PC to another?

Tags: eclipse, installation, project

I'm new to Eclipse, there is a project at work that is set up and running, I want to set it up just like that on my home PC so I can look at it in my spare time, so I zipped up the project directory, and unzipped it on my home PC, but it didn't work like Netbeans, seems missing lots of parts/plug-ings ? How do I know what plug-ins are needed for the project at work, so I can install them at home, the project is large and someone else developed it, is there a way in Eclipse to zip up all the plugins related to the project with the project and unzip and install them automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to reproduce the installed plugins should be *File->Export->Install->Installed Items to File*. The resulting file can be imported on your machine using *File->Import->Install->Software items from file* and will lead to installing all plugins which are available on the first machine.

Notes:

- This requires that the plugins from the first machine can be found via public update sites, as that exported file will only contain a list of meta data from where to install the plugins, not the actual jar files.
- The export includes all plugins of the first machine. You can deselect some of them, but there is no automated way to find only the ones needed for your project.
- Requires Eclipse 3.7 or newer.